# South tries to migrate django.contrib.auth

Tags: django, django-south

On django 1.5, south keeps trying to migrate django.contrib.auth, which obviously doesn't work. There are no migrations folders in my project, and the database is fresh - there are no rows anywhere. Upon running syncdb, I get

```
Synced:
 > django.contrib.contenttypes
 > django.contrib.sessions
 > django.contrib.sites
 > django.contrib.messages
 > django.contrib.staticfiles
 > haystack
 > captcha
 > compressor
 > south
 > ajaxuploader
 > users

Not synced (use migrations):
 - django.contrib.auth
```

Anyone have any clues as to why south is trying to migrate django.contrib.auth? It's very weird.

Comment: What happens when you run ./manage.py migrate after this?

Comment: Sounds like there's a migrations package in the auth folder, browse your site-packages and remove it. If you wish to use migrations for installed packages, try to use the `SOUTH_MIGRATION_MODULES` setting

Comment: thanks, i'll check out the site-packages and report back. I just wonder how it could have gotten there...